# Webscrape javascript/ajax tree view with python or Rselenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I', trying to webscrape the javascript table in the left frame on https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en using RSelenium. However, I'm getting no luck.

I'm trying to expand all Diagnosis codes to the highest level to retrive the description and code, e.g.

Z80-Z99 Persons with potential health hazards related to family and personal history and certain conditions influencing health status

Z80 Family history of malignant neoplasm

Z80.0 Family history of malignant neoplasm of digestive organs

Z80.1 Family history of malignant neoplasm of trachea, bronchus and lung

Z80.2 Family history of malignant neoplasm of other respiratory and intrathoracic organs

Z80.3 Family history of malignant neoplasm of breast

Z80.4 Family history of malignant neoplasm of genital organs

Z80.5 Family history of malignant neoplasm of urinary tract

Z80.6 Family history of leukaemia

Z80.7 Family history of other malignant neoplasms of lymphoid, haematopoietic and related tissues

Z80.8 Family history of malignant neoplasm of other organs or systems

Z80.9 Family history of malignant neoplasm, unspecified

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var oInfo = new OntologyBasicInfo();
   oInfo.ontologyKey = "2019";
   oInfo.ontologyId = "ICD10-2019";
   oInfo.theLanguage = "en";
   oInfo.isLinearization =  false;
   oInfo.baseURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + ":" + location.port + '/browse10/';
   oInfo.ontologyLabel = "ICD-10 Version:2019";
   oInfo.usesElastic = true;

   

   var appState = new ApplicationStateInformation();
   appState.userLoggedIn =  false;
   appState.appMode = "ICD10";
   appState.scrollToEntity = true;
   appState.defaultShowGrayNodes = true;
   $(document).ready(function(){
       OBrowserNavigation.getInstance().navigationMode=NavigationMode.Browser;
       OBrowserNavigation.getInstance().initialize(oInfo,appState);
       OBrowserContributions.getInstance().initialize(oInfo.baseURL,OBrowserNavigation.getInstance());
   });

</script>
```

This is the js interaction

https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en/JsonGetChildrenConcepts?ConceptId=I&useHtml=true&showAdoptedChildren=true

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know about the js interaction link?

Comment: From chrome developer mode

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following approach. I limited the loop to 5 iterations. You could use 22 iterations.

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
url <- "https://icd.who.int/browse10/2019/en"
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

#########################
#### Click to expand ####
#########################
for(i in 1 : 5)
{
  print(i)
  xpath <- paste0('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[', i, ']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
  web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("xpath", xpath)
  web_Obj$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(3)
}

#####################
#### Tree object ####
#####################

web_Obj_Tree <- remDr$findElement("id", "ygtv1")
text_Tree <- web_Obj_Tree$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_Tree, "\n")

[[1]]
 [1] "  ICD-10 Version:2019"                                                                                      
 [2] "  I Certain infectious and parasitic diseases  "                                                            
 [3] "  A00-A09 Intestinal infectious diseases  "                                                                 
 [4] "  A15-A19 Tuberculosis  "                                                                                   
 [5] "  A20-A28 Certain zoonotic bacterial diseases  "                                                            
 [6] "  A30-A49 Other bacterial diseases  "                                                                       
 [7] "  A50-A64 Infections with a predominantly sexual mode of transmission  "                                    
 [8] "  A65-A69 Other spirochaetal diseases  "                                                                    
 [9] "  A70-A74 Other diseases caused by chlamydiae  "                                                            
[10] "  A75-A79 Rickettsioses  "                                                                                  
[11] "  A80-A89 Viral infections of the central nervous system  "                                                 
[12] "  A92-A99 Arthropod-borne viral fevers and viral haemorrhagic fevers  "                                     
[13] "  B00-B09 Viral infections characterized by skin and mucous membrane lesions  "                             
[14] "  B15-B19 Viral hepatitis  "                                                                                
[15] "  B20-B24 Human immunodeficiency virus [HIV] disease  "                                                     
[16] "  B25-B34 Other viral diseases  "                                                                           
[17] "  B35-B49 Mycoses  "                                                                                        
[18] "  B50-B64 Protozoal diseases  "                                                                             
[19] "  B65-B83 Helminthiases  "                                                                                  
[20] "  B85-B89 Pediculosis, acariasis and other infestations  "                                                  
[21] "  B90-B94 Sequelae of infectious and parasitic diseases  "                                                  
[22] "  B95-B98 Bacterial, viral and other infectious agents  "                                                   
[23] "  B99-B99 Other infectious diseases  "                                                                      
[24] "  II Neoplasms  "                                                                                           
[25] "  C00-C97 Malignant neoplasms  "                                                                            
[26] "  D00-D09 In situ neoplasms  "                                                                              
[27] "  D10-D36 Benign neoplasms  "                                                                               
[28] "  D37-D48 Neoplasms of uncertain or unknown behaviour  "                                                    
[29] "  III Diseases of the blood and blood-forming organs and certain disorders involving the immune mechanism  "
[30] "  D50-D53 Nutritional anaemias  "                                                                           
[31] "  D55-D59 Haemolytic anaemias  "                                                                            
[32] "  D60-D64 Aplastic and other anaemias  "                                                                    
[33] "  D65-D69 Coagulation defects, purpura and other haemorrhagic conditions  "                                 
[34] "  D70-D77 Other diseases of blood and blood-forming organs  "                                               
[35] "  D80-D89 Certain disorders involving the immune mechanism  "                                               
[36] "  IV Endocrine, nutritional and metabolic diseases  "                                                       
[37] "  E00-E07 Disorders of thyroid gland  "                                                                     
[38] "  E10-E14 Diabetes mellitus  "                                                                              
[39] "  E15-E16 Other disorders of glucose regulation and pancreatic internal secretion  "                        
[40] "  E20-E35 Disorders of other endocrine glands  "                                                            
[41] "  E40-E46 Malnutrition  "                                                                                   
[42] "  E50-E64 Other nutritional deficiencies  "                                                                 
[43] "  E65-E68 Obesity and other hyperalimentation  "                                                            
[44] "  E70-E90 Metabolic disorders  "                                                                            
[45] "  V Mental and behavioural disorders  "                                                                     
[46] "  F00-F09 Organic, including symptomatic, mental disorders  "                                               
[47] "  F10-F19 Mental and behavioural disorders due to psychoactive substance use  "                             
[48] "  F20-F29 Schizophrenia, schizotypal and delusional disorders  "                                            
[49] "  F30-F39 Mood [affective] disorders  "                                                                     
[50] "  F40-F48 Neurotic, stress-related and somatoform disorders  "                                              
[51] "  F50-F59 Behavioural syndromes associated with physiological disturbances and physical factors  "          
[52] "  F60-F69 Disorders of adult personality and behaviour  "                                                   
[53] "  F70-F79 Mental retardation  "                                                                             
[54] "  F80-F89 Disorders of psychological development  "                                                         
[55] "  F90-F98 Behavioural and emotional disorders with onset usually occurring in childhood and adolescence  "  
[56] "  F99-F99 Unspecified mental disorder  "                                                                    
[57] "  VI Diseases of the nervous system  "                                                                      
[58] "  VII Diseases of the eye and adnexa  "                                                                     
[59] "  VIII Diseases of the ear and mastoid process  "                                                           
[60] "  IX Diseases of the circulatory system  "                                                                  
[61] "  X Diseases of the respiratory system  "                                                                   
[62] "  XI Diseases of the digestive system  "                                                                    
[63] "  XII Diseases of the skin and subcutaneous tissue  "                                                       
[64] "  XIII Diseases of the musculoskeletal system and connective tissue  "                                      
[65] "  XIV Diseases of the genitourinary system  "                                                               
[66] "  XV Pregnancy, childbirth and the puerperium  "                                                            
[67] "  XVI Certain conditions originating in the perinatal period  "                                             
[68] "  XVII Congenital malformations, deformations and chromosomal abnormalities  "                              
[69] "  XVIII Symptoms, signs and abnormal clinical and laboratory findings, not elsewhere classified  "          
[70] "  XIX Injury, poisoning and certain other consequences of external causes  "                                
[71] "  XX External causes of morbidity and mortality  "                                                          
[72] "  XXI Factors influencing health status and contact with health services  "                                 
[73] "  XXII Codes for special purposes  "
```